# why text appearing at the bottom of div?

Tags: css

I have placed several paragraphs into div element but text are appearing at the bottom of block. What might be the problem? As well would be great if you can suggest how to make the blocks more responsive.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
    <div class="inner">
        <h1><span>What</span> Clients Says</h1>
        <div class="main-block">
        <div class="testimonial-block-1">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTLdI6QE_lvzsCy_6VTsikYLz0iPFnWSv2vbGVzbwgQA8OlEbpH" alt="">
            <p>- Staciya Trollio</p>
            <p>Customer</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
            and industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="testimonial-block-2">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTLdI6QE_lvzsCy_6VTsikYLz0iPFnWSv2vbGVzbwgQA8OlEbpH">
    <p>- David Soul</p>
                <p>Customer</p>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
                and industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry.</p>
        </div>      
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
        height: 100%;
        background: url(bg.jpg);
        min-width: 100%;
        background-size: 100%;
        font-family: sans-serif;
}

.content {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(16,21,26,.9);
    width: 100%;
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 40%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}

.inner h1 {
    color: #3170a8;
    text-align: center;
}

.inner h1 span {
    color: #ee8129;
}

.main-block {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.testimonial-block-1 {
    float: left;
    max-width: 364px;
    background-color: #fff;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin-right: 45px;
    position:relative;
  z-index:100;
}


.testimonial-block-1::after,
.testimonial-block-2::after {
        position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: -20px;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: solid 20px rgb(255,255,255);
    border-bottom: solid 20px transparent;
    border-top: solid 20px transparent;
    z-index:2;
}

.testimonial-block-1 img {
    position:relative;
    right:150px;
}

.testimonial-block-2 img,
.testimonial-block-1 img{
    position:relative;
    right:150px;
    max-width: 107px;
    height: 106px;
}

.testimonial-block-2 {
    float: right;
    max-width: 364px;
    background-color: #fff;
    min-height: 100px;
    position:relative;
    left:160px;
  z-index:100;
}

.testimonial-block-1 p:nth-child(3),
.testimonial-block-2 p:nth-child(3) {
    border-bottom:1px dashed #222;

}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/montyk/Lsjo988z/2/)

Comment: Because of the image.

Comment: it's because you set the img inside the div, you should set it outside of the div

Comment: thanks a lot, maybe any suggestion how to make blocks more responsive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for the images, otherwise (if you use `position: relative` , regardless of the settings) the space they usually occupy will remain reserved for them (i.e. empty) in the container:

```
 position:absolute;
left: -150px;
```

and create a `margin-bottom` below the `testemonial-block`s:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
        height: 100%;
        background: url(bg.jpg);
        min-width: 100%;
        background-size: 100%;
        font-family: sans-serif;
}

.content {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(16,21,26,.9);
    width: 100%;
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 40%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}

.inner h1 {
    color: #3170a8;
    text-align: center;
}

.inner h1 span {
    color: #ee8129;
}

.main-block {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.testimonial-block-1 {
    float: left;
    max-width: 364px;
    background-color: #fff;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin-right: 45px;
    position:relative;
  z-index:100;
}
.testimonial-block-1,
.testimonial-block-2 {
margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.testimonial-block-1::after,
.testimonial-block-2::after {
        position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: -20px;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: solid 20px rgb(255,255,255);
    border-bottom: solid 20px transparent;
    border-top: solid 20px transparent;
    z-index:2;
}

.testimonial-block-2 img,
.testimonial-block-1 img{
    position:absolute;
    left: -150px;
    max-width: 107px;
    height: 106px;
}

.testimonial-block-2 {
    float: right;
    max-width: 364px;
    background-color: #fff;
    min-height: 100px;
    position:relative;
    left:160px;
  z-index:100;
}

.testimonial-block-1 p:nth-child(3),
.testimonial-block-2 p:nth-child(3) {
    border-bottom:1px dashed #222;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
    <div class="inner">
        <h1><span>What</span> Clients Says</h1>
        <div class="main-block">
        <div class="testimonial-block-1">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTLdI6QE_lvzsCy_6VTsikYLz0iPFnWSv2vbGVzbwgQA8OlEbpH" alt="">
            <p>- Staciya Trollio</p>
            <p>Customer</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
            and industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="testimonial-block-2">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTLdI6QE_lvzsCy_6VTsikYLz0iPFnWSv2vbGVzbwgQA8OlEbpH">
    <p>- David Soul</p>
                <p>Customer</p>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
                and industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry.</p>
        </div>      
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  background: url(bg.jpg);
  min-width: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(16, 21, 26, .9);
  width: 100%;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 40%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.inner h1 {
  color: #3170a8;
  text-align: center;
}

.inner h1 span {
  color: #ee8129;
}

.main-block {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.testimonial-block-1 {
  float: left;
  max-width: 364px;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin-right: 45px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

.testimonial-block-1::after,
.testimonial-block-2::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: -20px;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-right: solid 20px rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-bottom: solid 20px transparent;
  border-top: solid 20px transparent;
  z-index: 2;
}

.testimonial-block-1 img {
  position: relative;
  right: 150px;
}

.testimonial-block-2 img,
.testimonial-block-1 img {
  position: absolute;
  left: -150px;
  max-width: 107px;
  height: 106px;
}

.testimonial-block-2 {
  float: right;
  max-width: 364px;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  left: 160px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.testimonial-block-1 p:nth-child(3),
.testimonial-block-2 p:nth-child(3) {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #222;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="inner">
      <h1><span>What</span> Clients Says</h1>
      <div class="main-block">
        <div class="testimonial-block-1">
          <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTLdI6QE_lvzsCy_6VTsikYLz0iPFnWSv2vbGVzbwgQA8OlEbpH" alt="">
          <p>- Staciya Trollio</p>
          <p>Customer</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="testimonial-block-2">
          <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTLdI6QE_lvzsCy_6VTsikYLz0iPFnWSv2vbGVzbwgQA8OlEbpH">
          <p>- David Soul</p>
          <p>Customer</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've changed the `position: relative` to `position: absolute` and added a negative `left: -150px` and removed the `right: 150px`.

Answer (score 1):

i think this will do the trick, i used `display:flex` to set everything in the right place i also removed a few of the `position:absolute`. i believe this will save you a lot of unnecessary code and positioning and will make your code much cleaner.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lsjo988z/3/

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="inner">
            <h1><span>What</span> Clients Says</h1>
            <div class="main-block">

                <div class="chat-container align-start" >
                    <div class="row">
                        <div>
                            <img class="img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTLdI6QE_lvzsCy_6VTsikYLz0iPFnWSv2vbGVzbwgQA8OlEbpH" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="testimonial-block">
                            <p>- Staciya Trollio</p>
                            <p>Customer</p>
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
                                and industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="chat-container align-center" >
                    <div class="row">
                        <div>
                            <img class="img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTLdI6QE_lvzsCy_6VTsikYLz0iPFnWSv2vbGVzbwgQA8OlEbpH">
                        </div>
                        <div class="testimonial-block">
                            <p>- David Soul</p>
                            <p>Customer</p>
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
                                and industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
        height: 100%;
        background: url(bg.jpg);
        min-width: 100%;
        background-size: 100%;
        font-family: sans-serif;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(16,21,26,.9);

}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
}

.inner h1 {
    color: #3170a8;
    text-align: center;
}

.inner h1 span {
    color: #ee8129;
}

.main-block {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.chat-container{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap
}

.row{
  display:flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.align-start{
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.align-center{
  justify-content: center;
}

.img{
    max-width: 107px;
    height: 106px;
}

.testimonial-block {
  width:290px;
  margin-left:43px;
    //float: left;
    max-width: 364px;
    background-color: #fff;
    min-height: 100px;
    //margin-right: 45px;
    position:relative;
  z-index:100;
}

.testimonial-block::after {
        position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: -20px;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: solid 20px rgb(255,255,255);
    border-bottom: solid 20px transparent;
    border-top: solid 20px transparent;
    z-index:2;
}

.testimonial-block-1 img {
    position:relative;
    right:150px;
}


.testimonial-block p:nth-child(3) {
    border-bottom:1px dashed #222;

}
```

for more information about display flex abilities you can read this really good explanation https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/